# How to set a fixed time offset for the setTimeout paramet when iterating through objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to click an image every 2 sec (+ an average amount of a few seconds)

But the way I wrote this would click all the image only with the random offset and not after after an increased amount seconds. How can I rewrite this that `wait` in `wait + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5555)` is incrementally bigger instead of just 0

```
 jQuery(".images_lt").each(function () {
        wait =0;
       (function(i) {
          setTimeout(function () {
          i.trigger('click');
          wait+=2000;
          console.log(wait)
       },wait + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5555));

    })($(this));
 });
```

How can I use a closure to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger the click event on all images after 2 seconds plus random delay, use the below code.

```
var wait = 2000;
jQuery(".images_lt").each(function (i, el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).click();
    }, wait + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5555));

});
```

If you need to increase the wait for every image add `wait += 2000 //For example` right after the setTimeout statement